# Expected identifier or '(' before @interface

Tags: objective-c, macos

First post and I am really hoping this is not a repetitive or solved question. I tried searching here and Google and while I have found similar `Expected identifier or '('` errors none of the solutions work for me.

Basically I'm trying to learn Design patterns and as I used to know a bit of java I am trying to use it as an opportunity to learn objective-c so I have a java program that works and an xCode project that I get the error `Expected identifier or '('` in my header file just before the `@interface`

this is my java solution (very simple I know):

```
public class Duck {

public void quack(){
        System.out.print("Quack!");

    }
    public void swim(){
        System.out.print("swimming duck!");
    }
public void display(){
    quack();
    swim();
        }

    }
public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Duck duck = new Duck();
        duck.display();
    }
}
```

and this is my objective-c version.

```
//duck.h
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

@interface Duck : NSObject{ //Expected identifier or '('

}
@end

//  Duck.m
#include "Duck.h" 
@implementation Duck
-(void)quack{
    printf("Quack!");
}
-(void)swim{
    printf("swimming duck!");
}

-(void)display{
    [self quack];
    [self swim];    
}
@end

//  main.c
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include "Duck.m"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Duck *duck = [[Duck alloc] init];
    [duck display];
    return 0;
}
```

If any one can help I would greatly appreciate it, and again sorry if this is a duplicate post

Comment: Tried to import <Foundation/Foundation.h>? CF is a C-level framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//duck.h
//#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> // or Cocoa/Cocoa.h

@interface Duck : NSObject//{ //Expected identifier or '('

//} not necessary if there are no instance fields
- (void)quack;
- (void)swim;
- (void)display;
@end

//  Duck.m
//#include "Duck.h"
#import "Duck.h" 
@implementation Duck
-(void)quack{
    printf("Quack!");
}
-(void)swim{
    printf("swimming duck!");
}

-(void)display{
    [self quack];
    [self swim];    
}
@end

//  main.c SHOULD BE ~main.m~ if using ObjC!!!
//#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
//#include "Duck.m"
#import "Duck.h"
```

Additionally, get in to the habit of using NSString literals; @"example" for if/and when you decide to advance into Cocoa. Good luck with your studies.

Comment: that has gotten rid of the errors I was having except now I'm getting Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'const char *' is disallowed with ARC because of the @ and if I remove them I get an Apple Mach-o linker (id) error

Comment: well, printf doesn't naturally work with NSString literals (and any objects directly). You would have to call NSString's method UTF8String or similar; so printf("%s\n", [str UTF8String]); I shouldn't have added that since it would add confusion and you aren't directly using any Foundation functions yet, so ignore my mention of it. You'll probably come to it at another time and it'll make more sense then. For now, stick to c-literals until you do.

Comment: Additionally, what's the linker error? Are you linking the foundation framework? -framework Foundation (clang syntax)

Comment: honestly I have no Idea if I'm linking the foundation framework! the error is duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Duck in '/Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/simUDuck-cjdliuccayhvoabhcvdtqwpoactu/Build/Intermediates/simUDuck.build/Debug/simUDuck.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o'. I tried cleaning the project but its still giving me the error.

Comment: Are you still importing 'Duck.m' in main.m? The compiler will let you do it, it's the linker that'll throw a fit. You need to import 'Duck.h' otherwise you're defining the entire duck impl. in both Duck.m and main.m, which is not wrong persay, but is not your intent if you're actually building Duck.m and linking Duck.o with main.o.. This is different than Java, where you can define everything in one inclusive module and reference that module everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler doesn't know what `NSObject` is.  If you look at the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you'll see that it's part of the Foundation framework, not CoreFoundation, so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

instead of:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you don't really need curly brackets on your empty interface:

```
@interface Duck : NSObject
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using import instead of include. Also, make sure that the CoreFoundation framework is actually part of your project.